# How to set specified row values in pandas based on criteria in the first row? using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I want to make a new column in my dataframe with a certain number of rows after the original row criteria to hold to a certain value. I have to do it in a way that does not involve looping through each individual row. How would I do that?

Here is my example - a dataframe of random integers:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(25, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
>>> df
     A   B   C   D
0   32  52  15  39
1   27  48  96  48
2   77   4   1  50
3   10  31  59  23
4   32   2  44  75
5   71  67   6   2
6   52  36  82  53
7   35  20  40   6
8   60  57  67  88
9   59  94   5  82
10  61  44  82  40
11  91  67  72  73
12  32  55  27  29
13   6  98  82  19
14  33  80  20  33
15  25  24  94   9
16  73  99  71  48
17  76  12  72  41
18  86  26  50  75
19  17  83  96  86
20  13  75  17  59
21  34  39  24  17
22  77  37  71  90
23  59  78  92  17
24  56  99   9   8
```

Then set a new column 'lt25' if the criteria is met:

```
>>> df['lt25'] = df.A < 25
>>> df
     A   B   C   D   lt25
0   32  52  15  39  False
1   27  48  96  48  False
2   77   4   1  50  False
3   10  31  59  23   True
4   32   2  44  75  False
5   71  67   6   2  False
6   52  36  82  53  False
7   35  20  40   6  False
8   60  57  67  88  False
9   59  94   5  82  False
10  61  44  82  40  False
11  91  67  72  73  False
12  32  55  27  29  False
13   6  98  82  19   True
14  33  80  20  33  False
15  25  24  94   9  False
16  73  99  71  48  False
17  76  12  72  41  False
18  86  26  50  75  False
19  17  83  96  86   True
20  13  75  17  59   True
21  34  39  24  17  False
22  77  37  71  90  False
23  59  78  92  17  False
24  56  99   9   8  False
```

Now the result I want is to take a value from B where we see True and set the next 3 values in the new column to the B from the first column. The results would look like this, but I am not sure how best to code it:

```
>>> df['nextV'] = np.nan
>>> df
     A   B   C   D   lt25  nextV
0   32  52  15  39  False    NaN
1   27  48  96  48  False    NaN
2   77   4   1  50  False    NaN
3   10  31  59  23   True    NaN
4   32   2  44  75  False    31
5   71  67   6   2  False    31
6   52  36  82  53  False    31
7   35  20  40   6  False    NaN
8   60  57  67  88  False    NaN
9   59  94   5  82  False    NaN
10  61  44  82  40  False    NaN
11  91  67  72  73  False    NaN
12  32  55  27  29  False    NaN
13   6  98  82  19   True    NaN
14  33  80  20  33  False    98
15  25  24  94   9  False    98
16  73  99  71  48  False    98
17  76  12  72  41  False    NaN
18  86  26  50  75  False    NaN
19  17  83  96  86   True    NaN
20  13  75  17  59   True    83
21  34  39  24  17  False    75
22  77  37  71  90  False    75
23  59  78  92  17  False    75
24  56  99   9   8  False    NaN
```

It won't always be the next 3 values. Some days I might want to set the next 4, other days the next 7, or whatever, depending on some other criteria not relevant here. But I would like to be able to do this without running a loop through each row.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create a mask containing the shifted values multiplied 3 times using `functools.reduce` (a built-in function) . Then, you can use `where` and `ffill`:

```
import functools as ft
N = 3
new_mask = ft.reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [df['lt25'].shift(i) for i in range(N)])
df['nextV'] = df['B'].where(df['lt25']).ffill().where(new_mask)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     A   B   C   D   lt25  nextV
0   32  52  15  39  False    NaN
1   27  48  96  48  False    NaN
2   77   4   1  50  False    NaN
3   10  31  59  23   True   31.0
4   32   2  44  75  False   31.0
5   71  67   6   2  False   31.0
6   52  36  82  53  False    NaN
7   35  20  40   6  False    NaN
8   60  57  67  88  False    NaN
9   59  94   5  82  False    NaN
10  61  44  82  40  False    NaN
11  91  67  72  73  False    NaN
12  32  55  27  29  False    NaN
13   6  98  82  19   True   98.0
14  33  80  20  33  False   98.0
15  25  24  94   9  False   98.0
16  73  99  71  48  False    NaN
17  76  12  72  41  False    NaN
18  86  26  50  75  False    NaN
19  17  83  96  86   True   83.0
20  13  75  17  59   True   75.0
21  34  39  24  17  False   75.0
22  77  37  71  90  False   75.0
23  59  78  92  17  False    NaN
24  56  99   9   8  False    NaN
```